# Разделение String на массивы с новой строчки

Tags: java, android, массивы

Имеется String, в котором с каждой новой строчки - новая ссылка (Вывел в название кнопки).

[image]

Моя часть кода:

```
 Elements image = doc.select("img[height]");
                         for (Element imgLINK : image) {


                            imageUrl = imgLINK.attr("src");
                          mega.setText(mega.getText()+"\n"+imgLINK.attr("src"));
                          String a = String.valueOf(mega.getText());
                                              System.out.println(a);
                        }
```

Необходимо разбить эти ссылки с новой строчки на массивы `String`.

 UPD:
Пробовал разбить на строчки с помощью  `String lines[] = a.split("\\r?\\n");`
Но если ввести                              `System.out.println(lines[2]);`, то приложение крашится.

Ошибка:

```
04-19 10:54:15.089 16952-16952/com.twikoffin.hackinformer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.twikoffin.hackinformer, PID: 16952
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
        at com.twikoffin.hackinformer.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Заранее спасибо, извиняюсь, если похожий вопрос задавали ранее.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException проблема в том что если размер массива не задан заранее, вы должны сами выделять место под новые строки. Поэтому если неизвестно сколько строк в массиве следует использовать ArrayList<String>.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - выход за пределы диапазона, в ошибке однозначно сказано, что длина массива - 2 элемента, а вы обращаетесь к элементу №2 (отсчет идет от 0 и элемент с индексом 2 это 3-ий элемент. Он в массиве из 2-ух элементов, как нетрудно догадаться, отсутствует)

Comment: @coder676 огромное вам спасибо за ответ, но я и сам разобрался. Ответ ниже, можете, если есть желание - глянуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Elements image = doc.select("img[height]");
                         for (Element imgLINK : image) {


                            imageUrl = imgLINK.attr("src");
                          mega.setText(mega.getText()+"\n"+imgLINK.attr("src"));
                         a = String.valueOf(mega.getText());
                             strParts = a.split("\\r?\\n|\\r");

                         }
```

Выводим результат:

```
System.out.println("Total lines: " + strParts.length);

                    //print lines
                    System.out.println( strParts[число]);
```

LogCat:

```
04-19 11:10:23.609 18607-18607/com.twikoffin.hackinformer I/System.out: https://cdnssl.hackinformer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/09122526/PSTV-HACK-310x205.jpg
```